# Different results from yield vs return

Tags: python, recursion, yield

I don't really understand how `yield` statement works in this situation. The problem says that given an expression without parentheses, write a function to generate all possible fully parenthesized (FP) expressions. Say, the input is `'1+2+3+4'` which should be generated to 5 FP expressions:

1. (1+(2+(3+4)))
2. (1+((2+3)+4))
3. ((1+2)+(3+4))
4. ((1+(2+3))+4)
5. (((1+2)+3)+4)

My code is as follows.

```
OPS = ('+', '-', '*', '/')
def f(expr):
    """
    Generates FP exprs
    Recursive formula: f(expr1[op]expr2) = (f(expr1) [op] f(expr2))
    """
    if expr.isdigit(): yield expr
#       return [expr]

#   ret = []
    first = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(expr):
        if expr[i] not in OPS:
            first += expr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            op = expr[i]
            i += 1
            second = expr[i:]
            firstG, secondG = f(first), f(second)
            for e in ('(' + e1 + op + e2 + ')' for e1 in firstG for e2 in secondG):
                yield e
#               ret.append(e)
            first += op
#    return ret
```

If I use `return` statement (the commented out lines), then the code works as expected. However, when I change to `yield` statement as the code shows, I only get the first 4 results. If the number of operands of the input expression is increased, then of course more results will be lost. For example, for the input `'1+2+3+4+5'`, I only get 8 instead of 14.

I finally figure out the way to make the code work by commenting out the line `firstG, secondG = f(first), f(second)` and replace the line

`for e in ('(' + e1 + op + e2 + ')' for e1 in firstG for e2 in secondG):`

by

`for e in ('(' + e1 + op + e2 + ')' for e1 in f(first) for e2 in f(second)):`

That means some 'information' of the generator is lost because of the line `firstG, secondG = f(first), f(second)` but I can't figure out the real reason. Could you guys give me some ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question and fix the indentation of your program. Wrong indentation is especially annoying in Python programs.

Comment: Sorry, it's because I'm not familiar with how the tag code works here. I've already fixed it. Thanks

Comment: tagged it as homework, as i got the impression that it is.

Comment: I think the problem might be in the code that calls this, can you show us how you use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're iterating over generators instead of lists in the yield version, specifically *secondG* which is exhausted after one loop.  Change the line to this and it works:

```
firstG, secondG = f(first), list(f(second))
```

Or, you can change your loop:

```
for e in ("(%s%s%s)" % (e1, op, e2) for e1 in f(first) for e2 in f(second)):
#                               new generator object every loop  ^^^^^^^^^
```

The non-yield version works because you return lists, which can be iterated over again, unlike generators.  Also note you only iterate over *firstG* once, so it's not affected.

Remember that this:

```
r = [v for a in A for b in B]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
r = []
for a in A:
  for b in B:
    r.append(v)
```

Which more clearly shows the repeated loop over *B*.

Another example:

```
def y():
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
def r():
  return [1, 2, 3]

vy = y()
for v in vy:
  print v
for v in vy:
  print v

print "---"

vr = r()
for v in vr:
  print v
for v in vr:
  print v
```