# How are yield and return different from one another?

Tags: python, c++, expression, rvalue, lvalue

I encountered this term frequently that this function yields somethings or this function return something. I'm trying to understand this and read few articles in python. Then I encountered same statement in c++ which says:

> some expressions yield objects but return them as rvalues, not lvalues.

Can anyone help in understanding these two terms in language independent way or in detailed manner so I can grasp it easily.

Edit - if they are different in both languages please explain in both or any one which you know.

Comment: I am not a C++ programmer but I think they are not the same concept in Python and C++

Comment: Programming languages are not English. Sometimes they use words differently than their natural definitions.

Comment: In English "yield" and "return" are synonyms in this context, but in Python `return` is used for ordinary functions, while `yield` is used for generators.

Comment: Does C++ have a `yield`? I didn't think it did. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7213839/10957435) doesn't seem to indicate it does either. The only `yield` I can find is one about threads which I don't think does the same thing as in Python.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a `yield` keyword. Without knowing the context of the quote, I bet they were trying to distinguish expressions from functions.

Comment: @OttovonBisquick In C++, an lvalue expression yields an object
or a function. However, some lvalues, such as const objects, may not be the left-
hand operand of an assignment. Moreover, some expressions yield objects but return
them as rvalues, not lvalues.

Comment: @OttovonBisquick this was the whole statement written over there

Comment: I believe my original assessment to be correct - they are trying to not make you confused between the keyword `return` and the evaluation of an expression.

Comment: I think that C++ 20 is going to introduce the `co_yield` keyword to implement coroutines.

Comment: @Chipster The `co_yield` keyword is new with [C++20 coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines). It's not literally spelled "yield" but the committee has a difficult time adding new keywords without breaking everyone's code.

Comment: Just wait until you hit the differences between a C++ object and an OOP object. Much fun.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What about your research? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037267/different-results-from-yield-vs-return), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695872/yield-return-vs-return-ienumerablet), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187598/yield-from-iterable-vs-return-iteriterable) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494900/using-return-list-vs-yield)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: Personally, I don't think the word "yield" in the quoted text (from some C++ documentation?) has anything to do with a `yield` statement in Python. It simply means "[produces](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/yield)".

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `yield` is used for [generation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators). For example:

```
def func():
    i =0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i
```

If I remember Python correctly, this should allow this function to basically pause execution and get called over and over again. This can generate some sequence like `{0,1,2,3...}`.

On the other hand, `return` just returns a single value and ends execution:

```
def func():
    i =0
    while True:
        i += 1
        return i
```

This should always return `0`, since the function ends execution completely so `i` goes out of scope every time.

---

On the other hand, C++ has no direct real equivalent to `yield` as far as I'm aware (except for apparently [in the new C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), which is adding an equivalent), where as it does have an equivalent (in all versions) to `return` here. It is, of course, called `return`.

That said, C++ can achieve something similar to our yield example using [static variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static):

```
int func() {
    static i = 0;
    return i++;
}
```

However, that is not to say that static variables are replacements for `yield` in C++. It's just that you can sort of achieve the same thing in C++ with static variables in this (and possibly other) example(s).

---

So, in short, `return` ends execution of a function in both languages whereas `yield` allows a function to sort of resume execution. There is no real equivalent for Python's `yield` in C++ until at least [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines).

Comment: @martineau thanks. It there anything else I missed? It's like I say, my Python is rusty.

Comment: Thanks. I added the link to the answer--and read it too, of course. :D

Comment: Is that better, or do I still need the global?

Comment: No, using a global isn't a requirement (and using a local like that is better). Again, I apologize, and will delete my earlier comments. Note there's no reason for a loop in the version using `return`.

Comment: It's all good. It's not your job to make sure my Python is correct. I sure appreciate it.

Comment: Side note: the loop in `return` is just to illustrate a point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to iterate over an entire database of objects? That's what I tried my first time, and it quickly consumed all 16GB of my memory and ground my system to a halt. This is why generators exist - to load data in as needed instead of all at once (and probably a few other uses as well). Try reading [this](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) post, it has a few examples and will go into more detail.